# Lilypond - cannot use variables as part of \addlyrics

Tags: lilypond

For some reason, this works:

```
\addlyrics {Drei -- del, drei -- del, drei -- del, I made it out of clay
    When it's dry and rea -- dy, o drei -- del I shall play}
```

and this doesn't:

```
thing = {Drei -- del, drei -- del, drei -- del, I made it out of clay
    When it's dry and rea -- dy, o drei -- del I shall play}
\addlyrics {\thing}
```

I've tried putting \addlyrics inside the variable, adding and removing { }, and everything else I can think of.  Documentation doesn't address this case specifically, but I'm using variables all over the place with few problems, except here.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
thing = \addLyrics {Drei -- del, drei -- del, drei -- del, I made it out of clay
    When it's dry and rea -- dy, o drei -- del I shall play}
\thing
```

After actually trying that, it doesn't work!  LilyPond doesn't know what `addlyrics` is outside of the `\score` block.  So let's try this:

```
\version "2.19.83"

theLyrics = \lyricmode { 
  Drei -- del, drei -- del, drei -- del, I made it out of clay
  When it's dry and rea -- dy, o drei -- del I shall play
}

melody = \relative {
  g'8 e g e g e r e |
  g8 g f e d4 r |
  f8 d f d f d r d |
  g8 f e d c4 r |
}

\score {
  \new Staff \melody 
  \addlyrics \theLyrics
  \layout {}
  \midi {}
}
```